# Unwanted folder in path but not traceable to .tcshrc

Tags: shell

Earlier this morning, I had a problem where a folder ("/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin") kept getting added to my $PATH when I didn't want it to be in there at all. I fixed it by adding 'setenv PATH ""' in my .tcshrc file right before I actually set up my path. However if I add "echo $PATH" in my .tcshrc file right above where I reset PATH to the empty string and create a new terminal, it shows my $PATH set up the incorrect way. What's causing this and where can I go to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, what was happening was that my .tcshrc was sourcing all of the csh files in /etc/profile.d/. One of these was qt.csh, which added that folder to my path.